# If else condition is not working correctly

Tags: java

I'm writing just a draft of code to practice because I'm new to java, I have a question about the if else statement, this is my code here:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hospital h = new Hospital("Josh", "doctor");
        Hospital h1 = new Hospital("Susan", "nurse");
        
        Hospital [] hospital = {h, h1};
        for (int i = 0; i<hospital.length; i++){
            hospital[i].displayInformation();
        }
    }
}

class Hospital{
    String name;
    String type;
    int money;
    Hospital(){

    }
    Hospital(String name, String type){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
    //modify value of type
    public void setType(String tmpType){
        this.type = tmpType;
    }
    //printing salary
    public int Salary(){
        Doctor d = new Doctor();
        Nurse n = new Nurse();
        if (n.nurse().equals("nurse")){
            return this.money = 2000;
        } else if(d.doctor().equals("doctor")){
            return this.money = 5000;
        } else {
            return this.money = 0;
        }
    }
    //method to display
    public void displayInformation(){
        System.out.println("Name: "+ this.name);
        System.out.println("Salary: "+ Salary());
    }
}
class Doctor extends Hospital{
    String doctor;
    
    public String doctor(){
        this.doctor = "doctor";
        setType(this.doctor);
        return this.doctor;
    }
}
class Nurse extends Hospital{
    String nurse;
    
    public String nurse(){
        this.nurse = "nurse";
        setType(this.nurse);
        return this.nurse;
    }
}
```

The things is my if else statement in Hospital class is not working properly, I get an output like this:

```
Name: Josh
Call this!
Salary: 2000
Name: Susan
Call this!
Salary: 2000
```

The salary for Josh must be 5000, can you guys help me out with this, I know I can use this.type, but I want to practice calling from the other inherited class, can you show we how to do it?

Comment: Look carefully at the logic in your program. `if (n.nurse().equals("nurse"))` is always `true` so the `else` part will never be executed.

Comment: And in your Salary() method you create new nurse and doctor and they have nothing to do with Josh.

Comment: Also a `doctor` and a `nurse` should not be of the type `hospital`. Please create a `person` class and use that to extend from.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks Jesper!

Comment: Oh, I understand now, thanks a lot guys

Comment: This construction within salary() is not good. Overwrite salary() in the subclasses of Nurse and Doctor and handle the money there. There is no need for this if-then-else.

Answer (score 0):

`n` is always nurse, you need to check the type , instead of

```
if (n.nurse().equals("nurse")){
```

Use type

```
if ("nurse".equals(type)) {
```

Same logic for checking `d` which is always a doctor

Also change Hospital class name to a more suitable class as Person or HospitalEmployee

Comment: Technically correct, but maybe bad advice for a learning programmer: Using such type checks usually indicates a badly designed class structure (using `instanceof` would not make it better) - e.g. a `Nurse` object should know its salary.

Answer (score 0):

i apologyze for my bad english

the problem is:
a Nurse is instancied so if you ask: is a Nurse instancied with name Nurse?
Java will say yes ofc.
try to print the String too and you will see
try to put Doctor in the if and Nurse in the elsif you will see that it's the same problem

you should try to create one class instead of two for the HospitalWorker

you give as parameter to the constructor of your class : HospitalWorker a String with Doctor or Nurse
and add a getter of the string into this class

```
if(this.getJob() == "Nurse")
{
 ...
}
elsif(this.getJob() == "Doctor")
{
 ....
}
```

this should work in my mind